# Easily test branch configuration settings

Tags: git, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

Can I easily test from the CLI if a certain branch would be matched by the following branch configuration in the Team City settings? I am assuming this branch config actually relies on some Git internals.

```
+:refs/heads/develop
+:refs/heads/xmas-lottery-hotfix-branch
+:refs/heads/hotfix*
```

For instance, I would like to test if `hotfix/foo` would be covered by this config, or if I would need to change it. Simply sending empty commits to various branches and see if it triggers a build in TC is not easy and quick testing, although that works as well ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config above directly references the file system layout of git. If you dive into the `.git` folder of your cloned repo you will find a `refs` folder containing several directories and subdirectories. These correspond to local (in `heads`) and remote branches. They might also contain other special branches (like `pulls` on GitHub).

To check of a config matches one or several branches you can just use the normal options afforded to you by your shell (here using Bash on my local Sinon repo):

```
echo sinon/.git/refs/*/*zam*
sinon/.git/refs/heads/zamnuts-restore-etters-1124 sinon/.git/refs/remotes/zamnuts
```

This shows that a branch specifier of `refs/*/*zam*` would match these two branches (one locally checked out pull request and a remote branch). It should be very easy to modify this to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This menu will list every branch that TeamCity has detected using your branch config settings. It updates every time the VCS root is polled; every 60 seconds by default.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is of course better than pushing commits, but hoping I could somehow use git internals to check a branch specifier.

Comment: as far as I know, you can't, but I'm not really a git expert so maybe.

Comment: See my additional answer.